# How to find RSS from website in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to a web page and find the RSS from the website.  Can anybody suggest how I would go about finding the RSS for a website programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I would use XPAth and parse the HTML. To find rss+xml use XPath expression `//link[@type=\"application/rss+xml\"]/@href` and to find atom+xml use `//link[@type=\"application/atom+xml\"]/@href`

Something like the code snippet below which uses the lib2xml parser and a wrapper I've built based on [hpple wrapper](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). But you can use it for some pseudocode ideas. It returns an array of feed urls as NSURL's. This code also assumes you have the HTML you wish to search in a NSData structure.

```
-(NSArray *)getRSSFeedsUrlFromData:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableArray *rssFeeds = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];  
    Document *doc = [[Document alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

    //rss+xml
    NSString *kXPathQuery1 = @"//link[@type=\"application/rss+xml\"]/@href";
    NSArray *elements1 = [doc search:kXPathQuery1];
    for  (DocumentElement *element in elements1) {
        [rssFeeds addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:[element content]]];
    }

    //atom+xml
    NSString *kXPathQuery3 = @"//link[@type=\"application/atom+xml\"]/@href";
    NSArray *elements3 = [doc search:kXPathQuery3];
    for  (DocumentElement *element in elements3) {
        [rssFeeds addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:[element content]]];
    }

    [doc release];
    return rssFeeds;
}
```

Comment: sir when i implement this method it shows 16 errors as"'Document' undeclared (first use in this function)" what can i do sir

Comment: It was code I used as pseudo-type code for you. The Document & DocumentElement objects are not standard SDK classes. I wrote them myself and based them on the hpple lib2xml parser as linked in my answer. This is not a copy-and-paste answer but is an approach I have used in the past. You asked for suggestion, and I gave you one!